# Understanding the Facebook Audiences API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking to set up the Facebook Audiences API into my PC game but I'm a bit confused about how Facebook matches this to a real-world user.

I don't collect any user data in my game other than a unique userID. If I use the "External Identifiers" example in the [FB documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api) and push the userID back to Facebook, how does FB then match this to a Facebook user? Do they just collect IP address from the payload and use the userID to find a unique user or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Unless players of your game can use their facebook accounts to create user id's for your game, it is unlikely that you will be able to create audiences based on this data. Facebook isn't interested in the usernames of people who play your games, they would have no reason to store this information.

One thing you could do is allow players to create an account by signing in with their facebook id. This would let you put them on an advertising list, without having to try to match up user names to a game that facebook doesn't know about.

Here's a link to a quick start for Facebook Connect, which would allow you to do what I detailed above.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart